# Equal/Assign two JTrees in Java

Tags: java, jtree

Step1-First I create a First Jtree.

Step2-Then using this Jtree I created set of JTrees and added to HashMap with some calculated weight value.

Step3-Then I select one JTree from this HashMap.

Step4-Now I want to repeat this from step2 to step3.

Befre repeat it I want to take only selected tree for future procedure.
But It take final HashMap  adding tree to reaping procedure. I updated same tree and added to HashMap.

```
        public class JavaTree extends JFrame {

            public static HashMap<String, DefaultMutableTreeNode> nodeReg = new HashMap<String, DefaultMutableTreeNode>();

            public static void main(String[] args) {

            }

            public JTree method1() {

                HashMap<JTree, Double> value = new HashMap<JTree, Double>();

                //create tree root
                DefaultMutableTreeNode Treeroot = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new NodeInfor3(rootNode,x1));

                //create tree
                JTree firstTree = new JTree(Treeroot);
                add(firstTree);

                // create the child nodes
                DefaultMutableTreeNode node1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new NodeInfor3(nodeName1, x2));
                DefaultMutableTreeNode node2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new NodeInfor3(nodeName2), x3));
                nodeReg.put(rootNode, Treeroot);
                nodeReg.put(nodeName1), node1);
                nodeReg.put(nodeName2, node2);

                Treeroot.add(node1);
                Treeroot.add(node2);

                this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                this.setTitle("First JTree");
                this.pack();
                this.setVisible(true);



                for (Map.Entry m1 : newNodeSet.entrySet()) {-----forloop X

                    for (Map.Entry m3 : TargetNodes.entrySet()) { -----forloop Y

                        DefaultMutableTreeNode targetNode = nodeReg.get(nodeName3);

                        targetNode.add(newAddingNode);

                        tree2 = new JTree(Treeroot);
                        add(tree2);


                        //ADD TO CALCULATION 

                        WeghtOfSubTrees.put(tree2, calculated value));

                    }

                    //find maximum value with tree-using WeightOfSubTrees HashMap
                     I take selected Jtree name as a SELECTEDTREE
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------               
                    //THEN I WANT TO REPEAT. BUT WANT TO TAKE SELECTED TREE TO ABOVE PROCEDURE. IT TOOK FINAL VALUE OF HASHmAP. 

                    tree2.removeAll(); -------------------------------???????
                    tree2 =SELECTEDTREE;-----------------------???????
      -------------------------------------------------------------------------             
                    WeghtOfSubTrees.clear();

                }

                this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                this.setTitle("New tree");
                this.pack();
                this.setVisible(true);

            }
        }
```

I included editing points in the above code. May be it will complex code. I think I want to assign new selected Jtree to first Jtree. I used following code part for it.

```
                    tree2.removeAll(); 
                    tree2 =SELECTEDTREE;
```

But, it don't work. How to assign new tree  for first created tree before goto`for loop X`?

Comment: I am really confused with your code. Can you post a working code?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But my code is very big. Because of that I add it as a summary. I am sorry for that. As I mentioned finally, Is there any way to equal one Jtree with another Jtree?

Comment: Ok instead of storing the tree itself you can store the model and pass on the model to the selected tree.

Comment: What you meant by "Model"? I couldn't take your idea.

Comment: Every tree would have a model. Based on the model the tree is displayed on the UI and Model holds the data. So instead of putting the tree in the map put the model into the map. instead of this `tree2.removeAll(); 
                    tree2 =SELECTEDTREE;` you might have to do this `tree2.setModel(SELECTEDTREE.getModel());`

Comment: Thank you again for reply. I tried it. But can't take the correct answer. It gave same result as the previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you share you are adding the nodes to the existing root and creating tree based on the same root. I have created method to clone or the tree.

```
    private JTree createTree(DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode ) {
        NodeInfor3 info =(NodeInfor3)rootNode.getUserObject();
        //NodeInfor3 node  = new NodeInfor3(info.name, info.getSpecVal());
        DefaultMutableTreeNode newRoot = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(info);
        JTree tree = new JTree(newRoot);
        copyChildren(rootNode, newRoot);
        return tree;
    }

    private void copyChildren(DefaultMutableTreeNode source , DefaultMutableTreeNode target) {

        for (int i = 0; i < source.getChildCount(); i++) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)source.getChildAt(i);
            NodeInfor3 info =(NodeInfor3)node.getUserObject();
            DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(info);
            target.add(newNode);
            if(node.isLeaf() == false){
                copyChildren(node, newNode);
            }
        }
    }

    private void refreshNodeReg(DefaultMutableTreeNode root) {
        NodeInfor3 node = (NodeInfor3)root.getUserObject();
        nodeReg.put(node.getName(), root);
        for (int i = 0; i < root.getChildCount(); i++) {
            refreshNodeReg((DefaultMutableTreeNode)root.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }
```